# What is the computational complexity of this function?

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I was wondering what the computational complexity of this function would be?

> 2^(log(n)-1)

the log is base 2.

Comment: you already have the answer. O(2^logn). which is exponential.

Comment: @DarthVader nope. OP asks for the CC of this function itself.

Comment: @DarthVader oh, and if you raise a number to a logiarithm whose base is the number itself, it's by no means exponential, it's linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on using what algorithm you calculate all the logarithms and powers. If you're smart enough to notice that this function is essentially a division by 2, then you can implement this in constant time (i. e. `O(1)`) for integers by doing a right shift.

Comment: thanks for that. so because the number would be divisible by 2, how does that make it O(1)

Comment: Yeah, this is kind of a weird question. It's sort of like asking: what the complexity of this function: Sort(). :)

Comment: @dgamma3 read the answer carefully. (and it doesn't need to be divisible by 2).

Comment: @H2CO3 sorry, could you explain.

Comment: @dgamma3 what this function essentially does is a division by two (remember highschool math? Great.) To divide an integer by two, you can perform a right shift on it (by 1 bit) which is a constant-time operation. (Hint: you should probably not be asking anout CC yet if you don't know what a right shift is, or even what this function does.)